# How to restrict Microsoft Graph API access to specific groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am currently working with Azure AD and the Microsoft Graph API, where I've successfully retrieved all groups and users using the API. However, I need to restrict access to specific groups, such as students and teachers, via the API.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this using Microsoft Graph API permissions? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you brief your requirement?

Comment: do you want to restrict Api permissions to specific groups?

Comment: @Rukmini, Yep, is there a way to make sure our application can only access specific groups and retrieve information using the Microsoft Graph API ? currently i can access all the groups

Comment: Microsoft Graph API permissions cannot be restricted its tenant wide. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466029/microsoft-graph-permissions-to-only-access-specifi

Answer (score 2):

> **Note** that: Microsoft Graph API permissions are tenant wide and cannot be restricted to specific users or groups. Refer this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466029/microsoft-graph-permissions-to-only-access-specifi) by *Vasil Michev*.

[image]

Granting **`Group.Read.All`** permission means that the application can access all the groups at the application level.

Hence when you generate the token at application level and try to access the groups, all the groups in the tenant will be accessible:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

[image]

As a workaround, you can query groups with specific group ID:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID
```

[image]

Or query the members and their attributes in a specific group:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/members?$count=true&$select=givenname, mail, companyName, phone
```

**References:**

[Limit permissions to update a single Azure AD group via API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/905933/limit-permissions-to-update-a-single-azure-ad-grou) by ShivaniRai-MSFT

[azure - Is it possible to for users to only grant a subset of permissions on OAuth Authorization Code Flow? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694156/is-it-possible-to-for-users-to-only-grant-a-subset-of-permissions-on-oauth-autho) by Michal Trojanowski